# How to get C# WPF MVVM Screensaver use dual monitor?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, monitor

I am looking for an answer howto get a C#-WPF-MVVM-Screensaver-View on dual and more monitors running. I read several tutorials on webpages and answers here. However, never the coding samples worked on wpf.
Have someone a code exmple that works for wpf and Model View ViewModel Pattern?

I appreciate your help and thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks. I did it on Windows 10.

1. Create new WPF Window project for C#
2. Remove the startupuri / startuplocation from app.xaml.
3. Add a startup method to app.xaml.
  4.

```html
<Application x:Class="SeveralDisplays.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SeveralDisplays"
             Startup="OnStartup">
    <Application.Resources>
         
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Application = System.Windows.Application;

namespace SeveralDisplays
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            Window mainWindow1 = new MainWindow();
            Window mainWindow2 = new MainWindow2();

            Screen s1 = Screen.AllScreens[0];
            Screen s2 = Screen.AllScreens[1];

            Rectangle r1 = s1.WorkingArea;
            Rectangle r2 = s2.WorkingArea;

            mainWindow1.Top = r1.Top;
            mainWindow1.Left = r1.Left;

            mainWindow2.Top = r2.Top;
            mainWindow2.Left = r2.Left;

            mainWindow1.Show();
            mainWindow2.Show();

            mainWindow2.Owner = mainWindow1;
        }
    }
}
```

5. add two classes and ensure they are window-classes.
6. First / Main view, do not change here too much

```html
<Window x:Class="SeveralDisplays.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SeveralDisplays"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded"
        
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

8. first window code behind

   using System.Windows;

   namespace SeveralDisplays
   {

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
   /// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {

       public MainWindow()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }

       private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
           WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
           WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
           ShowInTaskbar = false;
       }
   }
   ```

   }
9. Second xaml as window

```html
<Window x:Class="SeveralDisplays.MainWindow2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SeveralDisplays"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow2"
        WindowStartupLocation="Manual"
        WindowStyle="None"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

10. Code behind:

    using System.Windows;

    namespace SeveralDisplays
    {

    ```
    public partial class MainWindow2 : Window
    {
        public MainWindow2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
    ```

    }

Answer (score 0):

you can do this simplified and smart. I use only a method inside app.xaml.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Shows the screensaver on every monitor. This is a multi monitor
/// application.
/// </summary>
private void ShowScreenSaver()
{
     ClockWindow ownerWindow = null;

     // Creates window on other screens.
     foreach (System.Windows.Forms.Screen screen in System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens)
     {
         ClockWindow window = new ClockWindow(screen.Bounds.Width,
                screen.Bounds.Height);

         // Primary screen does not have WindowsStartupLocation.
         if (screen.Primary)
         {

             // Maximizes screen.
             window.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;

             ownerWindow = window;
         }
         else
         {

             // Other screens need a WindowStartupLocation on manual.
             window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;

             System.Drawing.Rectangle location = screen.Bounds;
             window.Top = location.Top;
             window.Left = location.Left - 480;
             window.Width = location.Width;
             window.Height = location.Height;
         }

         window.Show();
     }

     // Sets every other screen owned to prmary window.
     // It closes all windows at once.
     foreach (Window window in Current.Windows)
     {
         if (window != ownerWindow)
         {
             window.Owner = ownerWindow;
         }
     }
 }
```

Here I added a View, which I initializes for several displays.

```html
<Window x:Class="Clock_ScreenSaver.Views.ClockWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Clock_ScreenSaver.Views"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ClockWindow"
        Height="{Binding DisplayHeight}"
        Width="{Binding DisplayWidth}"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        Background="Black"
        Cursor="None"
        ShowInTaskbar="False"
        KeyDown="ClockWindow_KeyDown"
        MouseMove="ClockWindow_MouseMove"
        MouseDown="ClockWindow_MouseDown"
        Closing="ClockWindowClosing"
        Loaded="ClockWindowLoaded"
        WindowStyle="None"
        ResizeMode="NoResize">

    <Grid Name="WindowGrid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="300"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="360" BorderBrush="#FFDF66" BorderThickness="5" Background="#2D2D30">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Foreground="#FFDF66" Margin="0,15,0,0" FontSize="25" FontFamily="Arial" HorizontalAlignment="Center">DIGICLOCK</Label>

            <StackPanel Background="#3F3F46" Margin="0,20,0,5" Width="280" Height="100">
                <Label Content="{Binding ClockTime}"  Name="timelbl" Margin="0,20,0,0" Foreground="#FFDF66" FontSize="40" FontFamily="Arial" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Label>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Background="#3F3F46" Margin="0,0,0,10"  Width="280" Height="50">
                <Label Content="{Binding ClockDate}"  Name="datelbl" Margin="0,8,0,0" Foreground="#FFDF66" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Arial" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Label>
            </StackPanel>

            <Button Width="60" Padding="5,5,5,5" Background="#FFDF66" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="#333333" BorderThickness="0" Name="QuitBtn" Click="QuitBtn_Click">
                Quit
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```